# NoSuchMethodError on jboss with hibernate validator 5.1.0.Final

Tags: java, jboss

I have an application thats deployed on Jboss eap 6.2. It uses hibernate validator 5.1.0
Since jboss ships with its own (older) version of this, I excluded this from my war's classpath using j-boss-deployment-structure.xml like below:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

It solved this problem but gives me this exception now:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
   5437         at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:133) [hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
   5438         at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:45) [hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
   5439         at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:236) [hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Fi        nal]
   5440         at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:229) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELE        ASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
   5441         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571) [spring-bean        s-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
   5442         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509) [spring-beans-3        .2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
   5443         ... 36 more
```

So i tried excluding the javax.validation package as well:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.validation"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This doesn't seem to help. Its still giving the same error. Any suggestions/help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

We had a custom validator which was using a method from version 5.1.0:

```
ctx.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(ctx.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate()).addPropertyNode
```

In 4.3.1.Final this method was **addNode** instead of **addPropertyNode**

```
ctx.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(...).addNode
```

Finally to make this work I ended up downgrading my application to 4.3.1.Final. I think this should have been handled by the exclusion in j-boss-deployment-structure.xml, however it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because of jboss's provided validation-api 1.0, but hibernate-validator is built on 1.1, so you can exclude validation api and dependent modules in jboss-deployment-structure. Note that javaee.api provides this dependency by default, so you may need to include required dependencies manually in `<dependency>` block.

```
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api"/>

        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider"/>

        <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>

    </exclusions>
```